# Could someone give me an example of what gauge freedom is and how it relates to gauge transformations?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, gauge-theory, definition, gauge-invariance

As title states. I am confused about this topic--what it actually means in practice.

Comment: "Gauge freedom" just means the ability to make a gauge transformation. In electrostatics for example, we have the freedom to add any constant to the electric potential.

Comment: perfect thank you. I guess I was just confused on the terminology.

Comment: You're welcome. Since that seems to have answered your question, I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Gauge freedom" just means the ability to make a gauge transformation. In electrostatics for example, we have the freedom to add any constant to the electric potential.